# Include tag "objects" in questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

getting a question returns among other things an array of tag **names**, it would be better if it return a whole tag "object" in other words: the count and fulfills_required (okay maybe not the fulfills required) as well.
Seeing as theres a max 5 tags, it wouldnt add to much

Comment: Sky has anticipated my reasoning, more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I am the one arguing for more data but in this case I will anticipate (and agree with) Kevin's likely response:

The tag meta is not relevant to a question and inclusion of tag meta would be a significant increase in response data as well as requiring an additional join into the tag table increasing the execution cost of generating the response.

All to support an unknown use case.

This is certainly a non-starter.

If you have a case where you would like to display tag meta, simply pull them.

My opinion only.

Comment: well it would be easier if tags had IDs, rather than having to use the filter parameter then having to go through all the results to find the exact match of the tag name as the filter returns what contains the parameter. This wastes time on my side. At least if there's some way of getting the exact tag like a "page" tags/{tagname} then there wouldn't be any need for this. How do you, Sky, get a tag from the question?

Comment: @jon - i have not yet seen a need for more 'tag' information with regards to a question other than the tag name, which I use to display. Can you present a use case for the need of tag meta which we could refer to. Discussing an unknown use case is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Well there's not really a *need* for it, just I need to put a popup of the tag and I though I might as well put the count in it.

Comment: @jon - from a pragmatic perspective, is there true value in providing tag meta in the context you describe?

Comment: Not really as I said but why exactly is the tag count there's not a lot/anything you can do with it.

Comment: @Jon - so let's look at this from the outside. Someone requests significant backend coding that will require regression testing,  server resources and increase bandwidth usage for a trivial (generous characterization) use case. You can see where I am going with this. Not trying to shut you down, just giving a reality check.

Comment: Yes I realize that (after asking)

Comment: @jon - ;-) mission accomplished.